# remove unused css from vuetify with nuxt

Tags: vuetify.js, nuxt.js, vuetify-loader

I'm using nuxt(universal mode) with vuetify with very few components that are actually being used.
I also add a few css rules of my self.
I tried to configure treeshaking with extractCSS, I think it works for the js part, but I'm getting a 350KB css file.
(I think) as a result I'm also having FOUC since it takes time to load all that css.

any way around it?
Is there another css framework that will work better with nuxt ssr?

Thanks.

Comment: please show how your loading vuetify, there is the full include everything method and a [only add whats used](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/a-la-carte/#manually-importing) method.

Comment: I'm using nuxt and @nuxtjs/vuetify module that suppose to have automatic treeshaking.